# How to get primary keys after batch insert in MyBatis

Tags: mybatis

use annotation @Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id") to get the generated primary key for single insert is fine for me , but when I use annotation @InsertProvider to make a batch insert , I have no idea how to get the generated primary keys , any comments will be appreciated . thx in advance

Answer (score 3):

Now Mybatis 3.3.1 had supported it. Please see https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/pull/547

Answer (score 2):

```
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Insert;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Options;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;

public interface TestMapper {

  ...

  @Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id", keyColumn = "id")
  @Insert({
    "<script>",
      "INSERT INTO test_table",
        "(column_one, column_two)",
      "VALUES" +  
        "<foreach item='item' collection='list' open='' separator=',' close=''>" +
          "(" +
            "#{item.columnOne,jdbcType=VARCHAR},",
            "#{item.columnTwo,jdbcType=VARCHAR}" +
          ")" +
        "</foreach>",
    "</script>"})
  void insertBatchTestTable(@Param("list") List<TestObject> testObjs);

}
```

**ps.:**

- Set keyColumn and keyProperty
- Use @Param("list")
- MyBatis will set objects keyProperty by reflection

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used annotations with mybatis, only xml. But, I have used both useGeneratedKeys and batch insert, together.

With Mybatis, you have to execute the same query ( One with useGeneratedKeys ) and call the insert repeatedly for each object in your collection. This will map the generated key to your pojo. Flush the session after every N records, and commit.

That's it. I hope you are not using Oracle as your DB. As, with Oracle you'll have to flush after call to insert, which beats to purpose of batch.